# Global Menu for JavaFX Applications

Tags: unity, java, menu, javafx

I know that we can enable global menu for Java Swing applications using Jayatana. But I am searching for global menu support for **JavaFX** applications. After searching on it, I have found that [setUseSystemMenuBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/control/MenuBar.html#setUseSystemMenuBar(boolean)) is used in JavaFX to enable same kind of behavior in Mac. But it is not working in Ubuntu.

My Java code:

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.paint.*;
import javafx.stage.*;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250, Color.WHITE);

        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        // Use system menu bar
        menuBar.setUseSystemMenuBar(true);
        menuBar.prefWidthProperty().bind(primaryStage.widthProperty());
        root.setTop(menuBar);

        Menu fileMenu = new Menu("File");

        Menu webMenu = new Menu("Web");

        Menu sqlMenu = new Menu("SQL");

        menuBar.getMenus().addAll(fileMenu, webMenu, sqlMenu);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: JavaFX Menu in Ubuntu]

Also there is a bug report regarding this problem here: [Gtk: Implement global system menu bar support](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8091321)

Are there any workarounds to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you found out yet?

Comment: @Socrates not yet.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code, and I'm not an experienced FX developer, but it looks like the line "root.setTop(menuBar);" is locating the menu bar at the top of your container, not in the top row of the total display. I think some other command is necessary. I only have Java AWT and Swing experience and may be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

If not solved already.
You can try using separate fxml file for designing the UI. Use scene builder for the same. 
[Scene builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDGzB.jpg), download the same from [here](http://gluonhq.com/products/scene-builder/).

I've tried the same in ubuntu 16.04 and it works fine.
Hope it helps.